# Apply DISTINCT to MongoDB Results

Tags: mongodb

I have a query as follow in `MongoDB.

```
db.Data.find(
{
FirstName:"John"  
}
);
```

I get the result as follow

```
FirstName   LastName  Location
John          Harvy    Germany
John          Doe      France
John          Baley    Germany
John          Kildy    Italy
............................
```

I want to apply Distinct for location but when I apply based on distinct("Location", query"), I only receive the location field as the result and not the other fields (FirstName, LastName etc.) How can I use "Distinct" so that I can get other related fields to the distinct field too?

(In Short, I want to apply a `find` query first, and then apply `distinct` to it but I don't know how to combine the two as `MongoDB` runs them separately)

Comment: What's the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation for this

```
db.Data.aggregate([
    { $match : { FirstName:"John" } },  // Your Query 
    { $group : {_id : "$Location" } }   // Grouping the attribute you want as distinct
])
```